# How do I add a background image in CSS with the image located in my project file?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding. Currently working on a digital resume. I'd like to add a background image in CSS without using a url. The image is located in my project file.

I have tried to load the image in chrome and I took the url from that to css, but it didn't load. Any help? Thanks

Comment: consider adding your `CSS` code, that might help us figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your CSS file is not in the same directory as your image, you may need to use relative path URL, here I'll show an example:

[Example directory arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EysNZ.png)

If your CSS file is inside the css folder, and your image is inside the img folder,
then you need to write your URL in your CSS file this way:

```
background-image: url("../img/your-background.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it be easiest if you used CSS to add the background image to your HTMl element. You can either use inline styles or create a css class in a separate file that you import in your HTML file.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

An example for this would be:

HTML:

[image: HTMl elements to add a picture]

CSS:

[image: CSS to add background image]

Make sure you use the relative path to your image file. Otherwise it will not load.

Otherwise you could use the HTML image tag:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp